# Getting "has established a session, but no BAYEUX_BROWSER cookie present" When Connecting To Platform Events Channel

Tags: platform-event, ruby-on-rails, cometd

I am working with this Ruby library (https://github.com/restforce/restforce#streaming) to connect to Salesforce's Platform Events.

Here is my code:

```
EM.run do
  client.subscribe '/event/My_Event', replay: -2 do |message|
    puts message.inspect
  end
end
```

I keep getting connection successful and not successful in quick succession:

```
{"advice"=>{"interval"=>0, "reconnect"=>"handshake"}, "channel"=>"/meta/connect", "id"=>"1x", "error"=>"403::Unknown client", "successful"=>false}
[COMETD UP]
{"ext"=>{"replay"=>true, "payload.format"=>true}, "minimumVersion"=>"1.0", "clientId"=>"xqp16hb2chcdsi58wg0sy23qfxfzd", "supportedConnectionTypes"=>["long-polling"], "channel"=>"/meta/handshake", "id"=>"1y", "version"=>"1.0", "successful"=>true}
```

There is a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50365162/cometd-bayeux-client-salesforce-streaming-api-issue) but that suggestion hasn't worked for me. I have also gone through [this thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000ApCYIA0) on the Salesforce Developer Forum on the error above.

And, after a minute, I get this:

```
{"clientId"=>"xhekc3efsx2nuz716v0p0wpf8ald", "error"=>"400::Client xhekc3efsx2nuz716v0p0wpf8ald has established a session, but no BAYEUX_BROWSER cookie present", "successful"=>false}
```

The only [Github issue](https://github.com/restforce/restforce/issues/161) I found on the above error still has not been answered for almost 5 years.

I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am the CometD Project leader but I don't know the details of the SalesForce integration, so my answer may or may not apply.

When a CometD client first connects to a CometD server, it sends a `handshake` request.
The server replies with a `handshake` reply *and* sends back a normal HTTP cookie called `BAYEUX_BROWSER`.
Every subsequent message sent by the client must have this `BAYEUX_BROWSER` cookie sent back to the server.
See [this section](https://docs.cometd.org/current4/reference/#_multiple_sessions_with_http1_1) and [this section](https://docs.cometd.org/current4/reference/#_security) of the CometD documentation for further details.

My take is that the Ruby library that you are using may not process the cookies correctly and does not send back the `BAYEUX_BROWSER` cookie on the messages after the `handshake`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. The library am using uses Faye (https://faye.jcoglan.com) to connect. My use case doesn't involve sending anything. I am just listening for events. Do I still need to send `BAYEUX_BROWSER`?

Comment: Also, I keep getting this: `{"advice"=>{"interval"=>0, "reconnect"=>"handshake"}, "channel"=>"/meta/connect", "id"=>"1x", "error"=>"403::Unknown client", "successful"=>false}`. Is this a problem?

Comment: OK. I have dug into the library code and was able to log what it sends back after the handshake. `{"channel"=>"/meta/subscribe", "clientId"=>"zf93v5oevhr0k1pr462in7f15dg", "subscription"=>"/event/My_Event", "id"=>"2", "ext"=>{"replay"=>{"/event/My_Event"=>-2}}}`. Does that look good? Am still getting the same error, btw.

Comment: My comment about the cookie was more about the implementation details of the client library. I don't know Faye enough to help you here. "403::Unknown client" is a SalesForce message that says that the server can't find the correspondent session ID. You may have multiple errors due to multiple causes here, so I suggest that you first get it working with the official JavaScript, and only later try Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications @sbordet